# How to get mobile number by using SIM card serial number only

Tags: mobile, gsm, sim-card

I want to get mobile number by using sim card serial number only.

Is there any way to get it??

Please let me know.

Hope to hear from you soon.

Regards,

Parmanand Soni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get the mobile number from the SIM ICC ID. 
The own number is included in the IMSI, but it's not usually possible to write an algorithm to retrieve it that will work for all SIMs, because it is prefixed by the country and operator codes, and the operator code has a variable length. 
Own number can often be retrieved via a USSD dialogue, but this varies from operator to operator.